# Como puedo editar el mensaje que aparece, al pedir acceso a la camara, con ionic?

Tags: ios, ionic, angular

En la tienda de app store me rechazaron la app porque debo modificar el texto del mensaje, en la imagen se muestra como your usage message y quiero poner un texto con mejor información

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para lo mismo. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

debes de modificar el Info.plist de iOS y agregar

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>El mensaje que tu quieras usar ira aqui.</string>
```